# Infinispan Cluster Programmatically

Tags: infinispan

I need to form an inifinispan cluster programmatically. I have done it using cluster.xml and that works but many documentations state that it can be done programmatically too. Any hint on how that can be done.

My code uses hot-rod client and infinispan 7.2.5

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly do you mean. Let me describe some of the options:

- You might form an Infinispan cluster programmatically by using [TCPPING](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/protlist.html#TCPPING_Prot) JGroups protocol and putting a list of you hosts there.
- You may [write your own discovery protocol](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/writing.html) and do whatever you would like to do.
- Since you mentioned Hot Rod client - you may also specify [multiple hosts to connect there](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_java_hot_rod_client).

As you can see there are multiple options, so could you please explain - what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am looking for the 1st option that you have mentioned. To be more precise let's say we have 4 servers(A,B,C,D).. I need to form cluster between A and B and another cluster between C and D..  This cluster formation needs to be done programmatically using TCPPING JGroups protocol